# Get records from a specific month and year

Tags: hibernate, date, hql

I need to extract records from a specific month and year using Hibernate.

My code:

```
if (!Converter.isStringNullOrEmpty(month ) && !Converter.isStringNullOrEmpty(year) ) {
    restrictionAnno = Restrictions.eq("year(dtControllo)",month );
    restrictionMese = Restrictions.eq("month(dtControllo)",year);
}
```

This produces a Hibernate exception:

```
could not resolve property: month(dtControllo) of: it.iet.ortles.hbean.TableauPresenza
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

One way I have handled this issue in the past is to take hibernate out of the picture all together by creating a view in my database.  So if I had a table `Event` with columns `EVENT_ID`, `START_DATE`, `NAME`, I would use my RDBMS to create a view that pulls the month and year from the `START_DATE`.

The view would look something like:

**V_EVENT**

> EVENT_ID, START_DATE, NAME, START_MONTH, START_YEAR

Once you have this view you can create an entity and run queries that uses the two additional columns in the view `START_YEAR` and `START_MONTH`.  This simplifies creating where clause statements in Hibernate/ORMs.

Comment: I tried to do it this way:DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(TableauPresenza.class);
  criteria.add(Restrictions.le("dtControllo", toStart(year, month)));
    
     criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("dtControllo", toEnd(filtroanno, filtromese)));

Answer (score 0):

There are two thing I want to mention:

first: year and month variables should cross

```
restrictionAnno = Restrictions.eq("year(dtControllo)",year);
restrictionMese = Restrictions.eq("month(dtControllo)",month);
```

second: you could try "lt" and "gt" methods for catching records in between.

```
restrictionAnno = Restrictions.lt(field, monthEndDate);
restrictionMese = Restrictions.gt(field, monthStartDate);
```